# How to use Delivery Date and Time Slot options in Product Catalog?

Tags: magento

I am starting to learn about magento and would like to setup a delivery date and time slot option in the product page.

If I am not wrong but I think I can do so by using product attributes or custom options?

Is there a way I can do validation of the date e.g. Delivery date must be at least 3 days after order?

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution?

Comment: Hi,  I am fine with both extension recommendation and or coding